# Order of Adjectives: "quantitative reverse transcription…" vs. "reverse transcription quantitative…"

Tags: adjectives, word-order, attributive-nouns

This is a general question with no specific sentence in mind. If a string of 2 or 3 attributive adjectives (or attributive nouns?) are used in a sentence, they generally follow a particular order (e.g. *a wonderful old Italian clock*). I am currently reading a scientific article where the terms

> *quantitative reverse transcription polymerase chain reaction*
>   and
>   *reverse transcription quantitative polymerase chain reaction*

have been used interchangeably.

- My question is, is there a construction where a change in the order of adjectives does not cause a meaning change or does not render the sentence grammatically incorrect?

Searching the Internet gives both results. Does the order have an impact here?

Comment: "Searching the Internet gives both results" does not necessarily mean they mean the same.

Comment: @JasonBassford I feel the thread that you indicated covers a different issue. This example does not fall into either of those categories, I feel.

Answer (score 1):

The basic concept is polymerase chain reaction (PCR).

A quantitative method is quantitative polymerase chain reaction (qPCR)

A variant of the first is the Reverse transcription polymerase chain reaction (RT-PCR).

And of the latter, the **quantitative** Reverse transcription polymerase chain reaction (RT-qPCR), or the Reverse transcription **quantitative** polymerase chain reaction. "Quantitative" can be used to modify PCR or the whole RT-PCR, though the abbreviation stays RT-qPCR.

HTH.